# How can I create a responsive navigation bar using CSS?

Tags: css

I've tried using the **`@media`** query to adjust the styling of the navbar at different screen sizes, but it's not working as expected.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar {
        height: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```